# how to understand the universal hash and the leftover hash lemma

Tags: hash, complexity

I always meet the leftover hash lemma when I read some papers.But I only know the defination of  universal hash and the leftover hash lemma.How to understand them and how to use them?

Comment: Presumably, you have already seen how to use them in the papers where you met the lemma. What exactly is it you do not understand? (You can find general presentations in good textbooks (Shoup), and even Wikipedia has a useful article.)

Comment: OK,thanks for your answer. And could you show me the textbook's name you mentioned above? Thank you.

Comment: A Computational Introduction to Number Theory and Algebra by Victor Shoup. You can find it on his home page, http://www.shoup.net .

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question (I'm hoping that you actually found it by now).